# Select out of a combined view with concatenation not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, concatenation

I tried creating a view with two values in one column using `+`, and the view was created successfully, but when I try selecting all from it it gives me this error:

```
select *
        *
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I tried researching this and the concatenation operator but to my dismay have found no help. Here is the code I used to create the view, and the select also.

```
CREATE VIEW CombinedNameEmployeePhoneView AS
SELECT (EMPLOYEE.LastName + ' ' + EMPLOYEE.FirstName)
AS EmployeeName, EMPLOYEE.Phone as EmployeePhone
from EMPLOYEE;

select * 
from CombinedNameEmployeePhoneView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators003.htm) in Oracle is the double pipe, `||`. The `+` is used for adding numbers together, hence the error.

The view was created successfully because Oracle doesn't evaluate the data when creating it; merely ensures that it compiles.

Comment: thanks. i love having my teacher assign us textbook that doesnt work with the DBMS he assigned us =_=

Comment: That's no problem @Mr.AwesomeSauce :-). I would highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/index.htm) or something like [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/) if you run into problems.